# Grid view hyperlink to open a new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

i have a hyperlink in grid view. i want to open a new window when i click on hyper link. i am able to open a new window. but modal popup is also open along with this. Popup should not be open when i click on hyperlink. it should be open when i click on row. not hyperlink which is part of grid view row.

protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

```
            SearchResult data = e.Row.DataItem as SearchResult;

             // Add click to open modal 
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("showDetail('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", data.Number, data.System, customerNumber, customer.CustomerNumber));

            // Choose background color
            DefineBackgroundColor(e, data);


            AddAccLink(e, data);


            AddJumpTomain(e, data);
        }
    }
```

private void AddJumpTomain(GridViewRowEventArgs e, SearchResult data)
        {
            //InForce JumpTo
            HyperLink jumpToPol= e.Row.FindControl("JumpTopol") as HyperLink;

```
        if (jumpToPolicy != null)
        {



                    string link = string.Format(Configuration.PolUrl, IdentityProvider.CurrentUser.GetUserName(), customerNumber, data.PolNumber);
                    jumpToPol.NavigateUrl = link;
                    //jumpToPol.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:cancelEventPropagation(event);return true;");
                    jumpToPol.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.open(" + link + ");return false;");

                }
                else
                {
                    jumpToPol.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which click event gets fired first? You can check in your JavaScript if the hyper link has been clicked, and if yes then suppress the click event of the row.

It's a bit weird though... to have hyperlinks in the row and attach a click even to the entire row as well..

Comment: Hyperlink click first. But how i can  separate hyperlink with row click event.

Comment: I think there are multiple options. You could check if the window is already open and if yes, then don't open the modal popup. Or you introduce a flag, which you set to true on the hyperlink click, and you check for it in the event of the row click, if it is true then skip everything, but make sure to set the flag back to false at the end of the event handler... and probably there are more solutions, depends which solution fits best your business needs

Comment: Soory for previous comment. modal popup open first. can you please give me some exp.